# WebStorm, unable to suppress inspection for undefined function

Tags: webstorm

I found [this documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/suppressing-inspections.html) on suppressing certain inspections, and I remember using it before, however for some reason it is currently not available.

I am working on a UI for a Unity project and we are injecting a JavaScript function into the DOM from Unity.  In WebStorm, the function is obviously undefined.  Unfortunately, in the "fix" menu, I only have the following options:

[image]

Here is what I'm expecting, based on the docs:

[image]

I remember from using it in the past that it simply puts a comment before the call, but I don't remember what it is.

**How can I enable this feature again?** Alternatively, what is the comment so I can manually insert it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as it's written in [Help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/suppressing-inspections.html) article, you have to press the **->** key or click the right arrow button next to *Create function....* menu item to open a submenu with suppress actions

You can also suppress it by adding a comment `// noinspection JSUnresolvedFunction` manually

Comment: Wow.  Did this change?  I thought it used to be more intuitive. Why would it be under "Create Function"?  I didn't even check the submenu because I didn't *want* to create the function.  As for the help document... my bad for not reading more closely.  Thanks.

Comment: Why does the screenshot in the linked document also show this in the root of the popup? https://imgur.com/ojS5ZqN  This is where I was expecting to see it.

Comment: Updated question, just for clarity